# Put my videos in the same line

Tags: html, css

i have problem with this 3 videos, i need put it in the same line (horizontal) but it appears in vertical, I try with display inline, table and doesnt work any can help me with this? here my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/goz6L2no/

**html**

```
<p><div class="contenidovid">
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Zhawgd0REhA" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>

<div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Zhawgd0REhA" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>

<div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Zhawgd0REhA" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div></div></p>
```

**CSS**

```
.contenidovid {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  display: 
}

.video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 74.25%; /* 4:3 ratio */
    padding-top: 30px; /* IE6 workaround*/
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-wrapper-narrow {
    padding-bottom: 40%;
}

iframe,object,embed,video,.videoWrapper,.video-js {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.video-js, img.vjs-poster {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important; //these need !important because IE wants to set height/width to 100px
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I would try using `float`.

Comment: add `display:inline-block;` to `.video-wrapper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is updated jsfiddle [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/goz6L2no/2/)

You need to make the div `float:left` and make their `width:30%` if they are 3 div's i have consider them to be divided into 30-30-30 and 1-1-1 as margin's

Making div float will prevent dic consuming the whole space and giving them width in % will ensure they resize based on the screen size.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am glad to hear that Zycerk. If this has solved your problem you can mark this answer as accepted answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of making "video-wrapper" "inline-block" and limiting the widths of each one. Also you'll need to set "font-size: 0" on "contenidovid".